# What do we call the ones who sing hymn?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is it just singer? Or there's a specific word for them?
Like "Hymner" (which I certainly believe it's not an existing word) or something?
There is Hymnody but that refers to the singing of hymn but not the ones who sing hymn.

Comment: "hymner" is in the Oxford English Dictionary, but it's certainly not common, maybe because the word "hymn" is rarely used as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to religious services, the singer is often called the **cantor** when singing from the pulpit or a **choir** when a group of people are singing together in a rehearsed fashion. These are to be distinguished from the rest of the congregation.

*cantor*: a choir leader; a precentor; or the leader of liturgical prayer in a synagogue [Merriam-Webster's]

*choir*:  an organized group of singers, typically ones who take part in church services [Merriam-Webster's]

Comment: In addition: a group of people (normally the general public or non-officials) who have collected to worship and/or to sing hymns have "congregated" as a "congregation. In Church of England organisations there is often a "Hymn Master" who selects hymns for use and directs their rehearsal and performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=hymner+meaning&*) / Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hymner)

> **hymner** (noun) plural -s :
>
> ```
>  one that sings hymns
> ```